# Android laying out images

Tags: android

I have got 3 imageviews. Now what I want to do is to layout one imageview at left, one at center and one at right edge of the screen in a single row. There parent view is Linear layout. How to do it?

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/previous" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/play" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" ></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/next" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Above layout is not working. All images are aligned at the left.

Comment: Can you please post some code that how to use relative layout in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to use wieghts. Set the layout_width to 0dp for each ImageView. Then set the layout_weight value to be equal on echt view. F.e. set it to 1.

For more information about weights: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=328

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Now images are in 3 grids but i want left and right images to be on the edges

Comment: Okay, have you already fixed your problem? if not can you send a screenshot of the grids you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Below is just an example modify it to suit your needs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:text="asd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="asd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <Button
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="asd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how it looks

[image]